# Opensuse 11.1 console won't wake up after suspend

Tags: console, opensuse

I run my home machine at runlevel 3, as I use Nomachine to remote into it from my laptop. I use s2ram --force to suspend it at night.

When I power it back on, everything works fine - my NX Session is still alive and I can connect again etc. However, the display doesn't wake up. I can still log in blind, but it looks like the graphics card just won't wake up.

Any ideas?

Comment: What graphics have you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue already addressed in the [opensuse wiki](http://en.opensuse.org/S2ram). Some of their reccomended workarounds include:

```
 - passing acpi_sleep=s3_bios to the kernel 
 - passing acpi_sleep=s3_mode to the kernel 
 - passing both of the above (acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode) to the kernel 
 - POSTing the video card from userspace after resume using vbetool 
 - getting the video mode number before suspend and setting the same video mode after resume using vbetool 
 - saving the VBE state before suspend and restoring it after resume using vbetool 
 - saving the PCI config space of the VGA card before suspend and restoring it after resume
```